# Understanding AWS Lambda CloudWatch logs

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using AWS Lambda with Python and I'm getting strange garbage in my logs when errors occur. Does anybody know what this is?

My stack is AWS Lambda with Zappa framework https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa, Flask and Python 2.7.

```
<trimmed>
dklIL2ZsYXNrL2ZsYXNrL2FwcC5weSIsIGxpbmUgMTQ3NSwgaW4gZnVsbF9kaXNwYXRjaF9yZXF1ZXN0
PGJyIC8+ICBGaWxlICIvcHJpdmF0ZS92YXIvZm9sZGVycy8xai81emN4anpreDI5Yjh0ZmdyaDJ5OTB3
dDgwMDAwZ24vVC9waXAtYnVpbGQtdjZYdklIL2ZsYXNrL2ZsYXNrL2FwcC5weSIsIGxpbmUgMTQ2MSwg
aW4gZGlzcGF0Y2hfcmVxdWVzdDxiciAvPiAgRmlsZSAiL3ByaXZhdGUvdmFyL2ZvbGRlcnMvMWovNXpj
eGp6a3gyOWI4dGZncmgyeTkwd3Q4MDAwMGduL1QvcGlwLWJ1aWxkLWp2RVlXSS9mbGFzay1yZXN0ZnVs
L2ZsYXNrX3Jlc3RmdWwvX19pbml0X18ucHkiLCBsaW5lIDQ3NywgaW4gd3JhcHBlcjxiciAvPiAgRmls
ZSAiL3ByaXZhdGUvdmFyL2ZvbGRlcnMvMWovNXpjeGp6a3gyOWI4dGZncmgyeTkwd3Q4MDAwMGduL1Qv
cGlwLWJ1aWxkLXY2WHZJSC9mbGFzay9mbGFzay92aWV3cy5weSIsIGxpbmUgODQsIGluIHZpZXc8YnIg
Lz4gIEZpbGUgIi9wcml2YXRlL3Zhci9mb2xkZXJzLzFqLzV6Y3hqemt4MjliOHRmZ3JoMnk5MHd0ODAw
MDBnbi9UL3BpcC1idWlsZC1qdkVZV0kvZmxhc2stcmVzdGZ1bC9mbGFza19yZXN0ZnVsL19faW5pdF9f
LnB5IiwgbGluZSA1ODcsIGluIGRpc3BhdGNoX3JlcXVlc3Q8YnIgLz4gIEZpbGUgIi9Vc2Vycy9kYXZl
bWFuL0ludGVybmFsL1NjcmF0Y2gvV2ViRGV2L2F3cy1sYW1iZGEvemFwcGEvY29udHJvbGxlcnMvZXJy
b3JfY29udHJvbGxlci5weSIsIGxpbmUgMTUsIGluIGdldDxiciAvPlRlc3RFcnJvcjogJ1RoaXMgaXMg
YSB0ZXN0IGVycm9yJzxiciAvPjwvcHJlPg==: 
Exception Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/var/task/handler.py", line 161, in lambda_handler return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context) 
File "/var/task/handler.py", line 55, in lambda_handler return cls().handler(event, context) 
File "/var/task/handler.py", line 155, in handler raise Exception(exception) 
Exception: PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+NTAwLiBGcm9tIFphcHBhOiA8cHJlPidUaGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzd
CBlcnJvcic8L3ByZT48YnIgLz48cHJlPlRyYWNlYmFjayAobW9zdCByZWNlbnQgY2FsbCBsYXN0KTo8Y
nIgLz4gIEZpbGUgIi92YXIvdGFzay9oYW5kbGVyLnB5IiwgbGluZSA5NiwgaW4gaGFuZGxlcjxiciAvP
iAgICByZXNwb25zZSA9IFJlc3BvbnNlLmZyb21fYXBwKGFwcCwgZW52aXJvbik8YnIgLz4gIEZpbGUgI
i9wcml2YXRlL3Zhci9mb2xkZXJzLzFqLzV6Y3hqemt4MjliOHRmZ3JoMnk5MHd0ODAwMDBnbi9UL3Bpc
C1idWlsZC12Nlh2SUgvV2Vya3pldWcvd2Vya3pldWcvd3JhcHBlcnMucHkiLCBsaW5lIDg2NSwgaW4gZ
nJvbV9hcHA8YnIgLz4gIEZpbGUgIi9wcml2YXRlL3Zhci9mb2xkZXJzLzFqLzV6Y3hqemt4MjliOHRmZ
3JoMnk5MHd0ODAwMDBnbi9UL3BpcC1idWlsZC12Nlh2SUgvV2Vya3pldWcvd2Vya3pldWcvdGVzdC5we
SIsIGxpbmUgODcxLCBpbiBydW5fd3NnaV9hcHA8YnIgLz4gIEZpbGUgIi9wcml2YXRlL3Zhci9mb2xkZ
XJzLzFqLzV6Y3hqemt4MjliOHRmZ3JoMnk5MHd0ODAwMDBnbi9UL3BpcC1idWlsZC12Nlh2SUgvemFwc
GEvemFwcGEvbWlkZGxld2FyZS5weSIsIGxpbmUgNzgsIGluIF9fY2FsbF9fPGJyIC8+ICBGaWxlICIvc
<trimmed>
```

Comment: Might it be an encoded error response? See: [DecodeAuthorizationMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an unauthorized request is performed by the user, AWS returns Client.UnauthorizedOperation response with encoded details of the request operation and reasons for failure. Only permitted users can decipher the content either using command-line or API. But decoding requires additional rights for that IAM user.

**For CLI:**
Use ' `decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <value>` ' .For more information refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html

**For API:** 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html